# Push to Vector in Hashmap

Tags: rust

**Goal:** Create a hashmap, add a vector to the hashmap, push to the vector

**Code:**

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert("first", Vec::new());

    let get_option = map.get("first");

    match get_option {
        None => println!("invalid key"),
        Some(v) => v.push("Chris"),
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*v` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:12:20
   |
12 |         Some(v) => v.push("Chris"),
   |              -     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `v` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
   |              |
   |              help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut Vec<&str>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hashmap is mutable, but [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) always returns an immutable reference. If you want a mutable reference to an element, use [`HashMap::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut).

```
let get_option = map.get_mut("first");

match get_option {
    None => println!("invalid key"),
    Some(v) => v.push("Chris"),
}
```

You'll see this a lot in Rust: a `_mut` version and a non-mutable version side-by-side. The idea of having mutability-polymorphic functions (a function whose `mut` status is a generic argument like a lifetime) has been floated before to the language developers, but it's usually been dismissed as too complicated and not worth the cost.

Comment: Wow I never heard of mutability polymorphism, sounds extremely cool. Too bad it's been dismissed.

Comment: @BlackBeans [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2a721y/a_safe_way_to_reuse_the_same_code_for_immutable/) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/414) are some additional reading materials if you're interested in the mutability problem.